Cannot Open Plasmo + Next.js Chrome Extension App in Chrome Side Panel
I'm currently developing a chrome extension using Plasmo, I actually created it from PlasmoHQ - with-sidepanel boilerplate.
However, the boilerplate is not opened in chrome side panel, like Copyleaks Chrome Extension. There is no any effects when I try to click the extension icon which is in the top right side of my Google Chrome.
And I'm also getting WebSocket connection errors when I inspect my chrome extension package.

Please take a look at package.json file here.
{
  "name": "with-sidepanel",
  "displayName": "With sidepanel",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Using side-panel API in an extension",
  "author": "Plasmo Corp. <foss@plasmo.com>",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "plasmo dev",
    "build": "plasmo build",
    "package": "plasmo package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "plasmo": "^0.89.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ianvs/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "4.1.1",
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.258",
    "@types/node": "20.11.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.48",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.18",
    "prettier": "3.2.4",
    "typescript": "5.3.3"
  },
  "manifest": {
    "host_permissions": [
      "https://*/*"
    ]
  },
  "contributors": [
    "louisgv"
  ]
}

